# How to use $model-> attribute inside 'value' of CGridView

Tags: gridview, yii

This is my index

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'tblvehicleimagegrid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
      'serial_no',
    array(

      'header'  =>'image',
        'type'=>'image',

       'value'=>'Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/originals/".$model->serial_no."img/img". $model->line_no.".jpg"',


      ),
```

The $model is not recognized inside the value because of the single quotation mark maybe. ANd without the mark no image is shown. Can anyone give an idea , how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $data instead of model ...Try this 
 In GridView you can access model by using $data->attribute.

```
'value'=>'Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/originals/".$data->serial_no."img/img". $data->line_no.".jpg"',
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
$data->attribute
```

or `$data->serial_no` in your case
So your value becomes

```
'value'=>'Yii::app()->baseUrl."/images/originals/".$data->serial_no."img/img". $data->line_no.".jpg"',
```

**Note:-**
 `$data is an object that stores the values related to your current record.`
**The single quotes are not the problem. You have to wrap it inside single quote only.**